# odd numbers in the column in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, modulo, sql

When I have do "WHERE COLUMN_2 LIKE 'B%'" it gives me odd and even rows , but how do I do COLUMN_2 that  starts with a letter B and it's with odd numbers. I have tried something like this but I am getting an error because it has letters and numbers.

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_2 LIKE 'B%'
AND MOD (COLUMN_2 ,2) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Note: This query ignores indexes on COLUMN_2.

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_2 LIKE 'B%'
AND MOD(REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_2 , '[^[:digit:]]',''),2) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_2 LIKE 'B%'
AND 
MOD(REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_2 , '[^0-9]',''),2) = 1;
```